# connection timing out

Tags: linux

I have a RH 4   , 2.6 kernel , running on a server in our office, this has our oracle DB running in it. we are facing continues disconnection issue when we try connecting to the db.  I tried accessing the server using putty and noticed some thing,

i am able to login with out any issues , but it gets timed out after a short while and after that every time i enter the password it rejects. But at the same time if I try accessing the Konsole the password is working fine. The connection via putty will work again only once I have restarted the server.

Can any one please suggest what to look for and where to look??

Comment: Is anything logged in /var/log/messages  sounds like you could have a failing nic

Answer (score 1):

There is a ton of stuff to look at for this.

1. As answered above, check /var/log/secure - and in fact, check all of your logs in /var/log to look for issues.
2. This is running an Oracle database, what system tuning has been done for the database? Installing Oracle ALWAYS requires some type of system tuning - in fact, on Solaris, the database will not even start until you've tuned the system. What does your /etc/sysctl.conf look like?
3. Ulimits? What is listed in /etc/security/ulimits.conf? (Again, goes with database tuning).
4. Have you tried setting a TIMEOUT variable from the shell to see if that makes a difference? (Like "export TIMEOUT=1000000).

If no tuning has been done, it's likely that the users are being forced off due to the resources the database is using on the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark but what security measurements do you have on the server ? maybe your connection is triggering something that is causing the block and when the server is restarted the block is gone and the loop continues.

Also, at the time of the block, when you try accessing the machine using putty from another computer with different IP, does the login work ?

Can you provide the log from /var/log/secure ?